# How do I get a UK ISO keyboard layout?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, hyper-v, internationalization

How do I get a [UK ISO keyboard layout](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/ISO_keyboard_%28105%29_QWERTY_UK.svg/750px-ISO_keyboard_%28105%29_QWERTY_UK.svg.png)? The [default English (United Kingdom) keyboard layout on Ubuntu 18.04 is ANSI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWpcr.png), and therefore my \ key keeps typing < instead. Is there any way to just customise the key instead?

Edit: Actually something really weird is happening, despite Ubuntu showing that I have the UK layout, it is still typing with a US layout. i.e. if I type shift+2, it returns @, despite the UK layout on Ubuntu showing it should return ". I will also mention that I am running Ubuntu 18.04 in Hyper-V, so there could be a problem there. But I have a UK layout on Windows 10 where it is working fine.

Edit 2: I rebooted and the keyboard is everything is fixed now, typing all UK keyboard keys working as intended, weird.